# HornetQ JMS: Configure max-delivery-attempts in Java code

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I have an EJB that is message driven which receives messages from a HornetQ (2.1.13) JMS queue. The application in question runs on JBoss 7.1. I know I can configure this on the server, using xml, like this:

```xml
<max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
```

The reason why I'm considering not using this way is because we perform some logic if it is the last try (i.e. try number 3), so I would prefer not to put this configuration in several places.

The code in question is upgraded from JBoss 4, where the maximum number of delivery attempts could be configured like below. However, this is very specific configuration for the JMS implementation used in JBoss 4 (which is not HornetQ).

```java
@MessageDriven(name = "SomeMessageBean", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "dLQMaxResent", propertyValue = "3")
})
```

Is there any way in HornetQ to set the attribute `<max-delivery-attempts>` directly in the Java code (preferably with annotations) of the Message Driven Bean? Or is there even a JMS way to find out if it is the last re-send (meaning I don't have to care about the number at all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With hornetq you have to specify it on the Address Settings. so you won't specify it on the bean. you will specify it at the queue level.

This doc here will probably give you a better idea:

http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/queue-attributes.html#queue-attributes.address-settings

(I'm pointing a 2.3.0 doc but this is the same since the first versions of HornetQ)

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this? This must mean that there is a fundamental difference between the JMS implementation in JBoss 4 and HornetQ? I am actually quite new to hands on work with JMS so I really don't know.

Comment: I am :) i'm the project lead for HornetQ. 
We didn't want to force to set these settings on every MDB. That's a property of the broker not the resource adapter. 

Look at the link I have sent you. that's the way to do it.. 

And HornetQ is a new implementation of a messaging provider, way better than Jboss MQ

Comment: I consider you a trustful source then. :) I had actually read the part you link to, before I posted the question. I guess that was the reason I asked the question, since I only found the way to do it at queue level. Anyway, many thanks.